# Java NIO Sockets clients request processing

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am trying to understand the NIO Sockets model and I have a few questions that I want to clear up.

1. Is it possible that you can register more than one Server channels with selector i.e.

   ```
   serverChannel_1.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
   serverChannel_2.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
   // and so on ....?
   ```

   So, by registering two ServerSocketChannel are you having two servers on the same machine on different ports?
2. What are the "keys" in this following nio socket model:

[image]

From what I can tell is that the long client I/O requests are divided into small chunks and handled one after another. i.e. say 10% of request from client 1, 2, 3 is processed at a time and loop starts again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. A `SelectionKey` Is the result of registering a channel with a selector. It represents the registration, if you like. It has as properties the channel that was registered, the event(s) it was registered for, and the event(s) if any that are currently ready.

   > From what I can tell is that the long client I/O requests are divided into small chunks and handled one after another. i.e. say 10% of request from client 1, 2, 3 is processed at a time and loop starts again?

No. How you handle client I/O is entirely up to you. All the `Selector` does is tell you which events are ready on which channels.

Comment: So, that means I can choose to handle a client's request all at once or use buffers to handle it a little bit at each time, right?

Comment: Entirely up to you. If for example you don't read all the data that is available, OP_READ will fire immediately next time.